# Internet Explorer 10 log in icons display

Tags: bug, login, design

I was trying to up vote a question in Internet Explorer 10 (Compatibility View turned off) while not being logged in and I saw the icons are not exactly the form they should be (or at least the way they render in Chrome):

[image: ie10]

It seems like deactivating `background-size: 326px 95px` on the `.icon` class solves the issue.